# How to setup PyCharm remote debug from complex docker-compose webapp?

Tags: pycharm, docker-compose

I already asked this question on IntelliJ forum but haven't received any answer.

I have a Flask App running on my backend in docker container, along with app there is  a container for rabbitmq, celery and mongo. So it is just a usual backend setup with docker.

Docker-compose looks this this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: api/
      ...
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis

  mongo:
   ...

  redis:
   ...

  rabbitmq:
   ...
  api_worker:
   ...
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    command: celery worker -A queue_conf -P eventlet -c 4 -l WARNING -Q emit,high,low,normal,process-message -n worker --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

I added a remote interpreter from docker compose to project's debug setup and it works fine until it sees a queued task. Debuger skips it. 
Debugger uses api Flask project as a remote debug project.

So my question is: what should I do to debug such a project? Run all the stuff in one container? Or adjust my debug settings somehow?

I can imagine that debug can't handle the code which is executed in different thread or service in which other containers runs, but I am not sure how it works because I am neither docker nor pydev library expert.

```
My setup:
PyCharm professional 2018.1 ;
Docker Engine 18.03 ;
Docker Compose 1.20.1 ;
OS MAC
```

Comment: Enqueued tasks are ran in a separate docker container if you want to debug tasks you have to launch a second debugger on the task runner container.

Comment: Another solution is to run the task in the main process instead of putting it the queue if debug mode is enabled.